# I need help to figure out how to loop this slideshow

Tags: javascript

I have this lovely simple code for a slideshow in javascript and I would like to make it loop. Wondering if someone could help me?

````
       var slideIndex = 0;
       showSlides();

       function showSlides() {
           var i;
           var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
           var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
           for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
               slides[i].style.display = "none";
           }
           slideIndex++;
           if (slideIndex > slides.length) { slideIndex = 1 }
           for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
               dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
           }
           slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
           dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
           setTimeout(showSlides, 3000); // Change image every 2 seconds
       }
   </script>```
````

Answer (score 0):

You should use setInterval instead of setTimeout

Comment: That works for a short time but then it starts to loop super fast at like a frame every millisecond.

Comment: Weirdly it seems to be working now with the original setTimeout

Comment: This is because `setInterval` is set inside the callback, meaning it will increase the amount of function calls per every time the function is called. It should work with `setTimeout`.